# inserting file name or file path in php

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

i am uploading files or paths in php mysql as shown below

```
$Image=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$Image=str_replace(' ','|',$Image);
$tmppath1="Pic/".$Image;
$Audio=basename($_FILES['file1']['name']);
$Audio=str_replace(' ','|',$Audio);
$tmppath2="Audio/".$Audio;
$Video=basename($_FILES['file2']['name']);
$Video=str_replace(' ','|',$Video);  
$tmppath3="Video/".$Video;               
$imagepath=$_REQUEST['imagepath'];
$audiopath=$_REQUEST['audiopath'];
$videopath=$_REQUEST['videopath'];
```

in this upload image and audio is compulsory
i write query as shown below

```
if($Image && $Audio && !$Video)  
{
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_Item(Image,Audio) VALUES('$Image','$Audio')";
}
else if($Image && $Audio && $Video)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_Item(Image,Audio,Video)   VALUES('$Image','$Audio','$Video')";
}
else if($imagepath && $audiopath && !$videopath)  
{
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_Item(Image,Audio) VALUES('$imagepath','$audiopath')";
}
else if($imagepath && $audiopath && $videopath)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_Item(Image,Audio,Video)   VALUES('$imagepath','$audiopath','$videopath')";
}
```

i want to insert either image or image path ,similarly video or a video path or audio or audio path. so that either path or name what ever is given should be capable of storing in my database and then retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just store the complete path with the filename where the file is, and then get substrings of the filename to get it ?

You can just had one sql query for all but insert some empty values?

```
$imagepath=(!empty($_REQUEST['imagepath']))?$_REQUEST['imagepath']:"";
$audiopath=(!empty($_REQUEST['audiopath']))?$_REQUEST['audiopath']:"";
$videopath=(!empty($_REQUEST['videopath']))?$_REQUEST['videopath']:"";
```

like this you will always have the same query

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_Item(Image,Audio,Video) VALUES('$imagepath','$audiopath','$videopath')";
```